# How to select some default value if there is no such column in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have a table that doesn't have a column "type". But I need to have my sql query having that column. When I run the query I get an error:

```
SELECT t.foo, t.boo, t.type FROM tabl AS t;

Unknown column 't.type' in 'field list'
```

I need something like ternary operator. I tried these solutions but they both do not work:

```
SELECT f.foo, f.boo, IF(f.type IS NULL, 'x', f.type) AS type FROM tabl AS f
SELECT f.foo, f.boo, (CASE WHEN f.type IS NULL THEN "x" ELSE f.type) AS type FROM tabl AS f
```

Is there a possibility to implement such a query?

Comment: Why are you trying to query against a column that doesn't exist?

Comment: The design of my system requires a 'type' column. But sometimes I get tables that temporary do not have a 'type' column. So for this case I want to have some default value.

Comment: In that case there's a fundamental flaw in your design!

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this. Assume you want to join 2 tables rows and one is missing the column:

```
   SELECT t.foo, t.boo, t.type FROM tabl1 as t1 

   UNION

   SELECT t.foo, t.boo, NULL as type FROM tabl2 AS t2;
```

You can replace NULL with a string "" or whatever you application desires.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is not the way columns work.  If you need to introspect your table to determine if it have this column, then you might try using data in the information_schema to get at this.  Overall sounds like a weird approach to me.  Why not just create all the tables with this column?

Comment: `Why not just create all the tables with this column?` Good idea, thank you. I was thinking in different direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you have a table with entries ... Some of your entries has got no "type" column filled in. To have default value, you need to change your table. You can change it using either phpmyadmin (set default value) or through SQL code.

This would be something on these lines:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255) DEFAULT 'London'
)
```

This sets each entry's city to be London by default

Comment: Not exactly. Some of my tables have got no column 'type' at all. I know how to set a default value on a column. Nevertheless, thank you.